# How to implement multi-action controllers

Tags: spring-mvc

I am pretty familiar with ASP.Net MVC, now I want to try some Spring MVC. I did some tutorial examples. In ASP.Net MVC, we can put many action methods in a single MVC Controller class, but it seems to me that in Spring MVC, we can have only "one" action method in a Controller class?

I am wondering to find out what are the spring MVC correspondence of the action methods in ASP.net MVC? Can we have many action methods in a single controller like how ASP.Net MVC does?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> in Spring MVC, we can have only "one" action method in a Controller class

I'm not sure where you got that from, but it's not true now, and never has been. You've been misinformed.

Look up `@RequestMapping`-annotated methods in the [Spring docs](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-ann-requestmapping), or the old-style (and obsolete/deprecated) [`MultiActionController`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/mvc/multiaction/MultiActionController.html).

Comment: Thank you very much. I just get started with spring, so my impression could be very "wrong". Let me try @RequestMapping or MultiActionController.